# Can I reorder the fields in a biblatex bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the verbose bibliography style in biblatex, and would like to place the URL and DOI fields at the end of each entry, after the (cited on page ...) field rather than before it. Is there a way to reorder the fields of an existing style?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the general case, when the fields you're wanting to reorder don't necessarily appear at the end, biblatex's `\clearfield`-type macros and the [xpatch package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) come in handy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate+pageref}{%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \clearfield{addendum}%
  \clearfield{pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \clearlist{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock}

\xpretobibmacro{doi+eprint+url}{\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate+pageref}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{eprint}{\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate+pageref}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{url+urldate}{\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate+pageref}}{}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text.\footcite{bertram,kastenholz,ctan,itzhaki}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm out of votes for today, but will upvote tomorrow.

Comment: @lockstep No worries. You did all the upfront work. I just wanted to post another way, which is in fact only possible because of your previous question about patching bibliography macros...

Comment: Let's hope that `biblatex` v2/v3 provides a user-friendly interface for this sort of customizations.

Comment: So many good answers! Sorry to swap acceptances, but this one's the one I'm going to go with (for compactness).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius From another one of your questions it looks like you want linebreaks before URLs and URLs only in the bibliography. You can do the first part easily by replacing `\newunit\newblock` with `\setunit{\adddot\par\nobreak}`. You can follow Marco's advice and edit the URL formats for the second part, but you could also use `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{doi}\clearfield{eprint}}`.

Comment: Thanks, that's cleaner. I also get rid of the "URL: " and "DOI: ", etc. I've figured out how to do that the other way, how would I do that using this code? Thanks again!

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius The URL prefixes are generated by the field format, so you'll have to edit those. For example, take format definition from `biblatex.def`: `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}`. You'll want to change this to `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}`. If you need help with the other fields, just post a new question.

Answer (score 12):

In the bibliography styles shipped with `biblatex`, the drivers for the different entry types (`@article`, `@book`, ...) typically end with

```
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

So one may redefine the `doi+eprint+url` bibmacro to do nothing, while the `finentry` bibmacro also undertakes the tasks of the original `doi+eprint+url` (instead of only typesetting a `\finentrypoint`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backref=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}%
  \finentry
}

\textheight=120pt% just for the example

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {www.tex.stackechange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The drivers for the `@online` and `@unpublished` entry types directly use the `url+urdate` bibmacro. You can't redefine this macro to do nothing because it is used internally by `doi+eprint+url`. Instead, you have to copy the definition of `@online` and `@unpublished` to your document preamble and remove the respective code lines.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
%   \newunit\newblock% DELETED
%   \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}% DELETED
%     {\usebibmacro{eprint}}% DELETED
%     {}% DELETED
%   \newunit\newblock% DELETED
%   \usebibmacro{url+urldate}% DELETED
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{unpublished}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
%   \newunit\newblock% DELETED
%   \iftoggle{bbx:url}% DELETED
%     {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}% DELETED
%     {}% DELETED
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Comment: Sneaky, but clever.

Comment: Excellent, this mostly works, but I get odd behavior: some entries end up with two URLs, one before and one after the "cited on" field. I'm trying to generate a MWE to reproduce the behavior, but it's erratic. Changing citations around, causes the effected entry to change.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius See edited answer.

Comment: Ick. Works great though, thanks!

Comment: @lockstep The `eprint` bibliography macro has the same issue.

Comment: @Audrey Many thanks -- I corrected the `@online` type.

Comment: Thanks for this very instructive answer. However, as it is 8 years old and biblatex has changed a lot in the meantime, may I ask: does this answer still apply as of today or is it outdated?