# Years before note with BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex

How do I order the outcome of BibLaTeX? I would like to have year before the note.
I currently just use

```
\usepackage{biblatex}  
 %preamble end

\printbibliography[title={Internet}, type=misc]
```

I have defined an internet source as

```
@misc{t100b,
  author = {Interbrand},
  title = {{Best Global Brands 2012}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.interbrand.com/en/best-global-brands/2012/Best-Global-Brands-2012-Brand-View.aspx}",
  year = {2012},
  note = "Visited the 19/12/2012"
}
```

in my internet.bib file.
It looks like

> Interbrand. *Best Global Brands 2012.* http://www.interbrand.com/en/best-global-brands/ 2012/Best-Global-Brands-2012-Brand-View.aspx. Visited the 19/12/2012. 2012.

I would like it to be

> Interbrand. *Best Global Brands 2012.* http://www.interbrand.com/en/best-global-brands/ 2012/Best-Global-Brands-2012-Brand-View.aspx. 2012. Visited the 19/12/2012.

Is it possible to get the year before the note? It is currently sorted by list af appearance, which I would like to continue using.

Comment: related (not duplicate): [Can I reorder the fields in a biblatex bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46804)

Comment: if you are only using the `note` field for the visited date, you could probably replace this with the `urldate` field, which take the date only in the same format as the `date` field would, and will behave as you want. but then again, as you are using biblatex, I would use the `@online` entry and replace the `howpublish` field with the `url` one (and no need to enclose the actual url in `\url{}`) as well.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is to choose a citation style where this is already implemented. For example, the commonly used `authoryear` citation style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{t100b,
  author = {Interbrand},
  title = {{Best Global Brands 2012}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.interbrand.com/en/best-global-brands/2012/Best-Global-Brands-2012-Brand-View.aspx}",
  year = {2012},
  note = "Visited the 19/12/2012"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{t100b}
\printbibliography[title={Internet}, type=misc]

\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex` will give you this output:

[image: MWE]

Which has the year before the note.

If you'd like a different style just look through your `$TEXMFLOCAL/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx` directory (or the parallel one on Win/Mac) to see what styles you have available there.

If you can't find anything that suits you, you might have to design your own style. Looking in `standard.bbx` will show you that `misc` is defined like this:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{organization+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

copying this to a new `.bbx` file and switching around the fields should get you your desired output. Just don't forget to initiate the file with the following lines:

```
\ProvidesFile{my_style.bbx}% replace this with your style name
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}% replace this with the style you'd like to build upon
```

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, since you are using `biblatex`, you have access to a much wider choice of entry type (the full list of which is in the `biblatex` documentation.

In your case, you are citing an online resource which using biblatex can be described using the `@online` entry.

`biblatex` also give you access to additional field which can be useful when describing online resources. The `url` and `urldate` are such entries. With the url entry, you do not need to enclose the the actual url inside the `\url{}` command as it will be done so automatically; and the `urldate` (which accepts the same date format as the `date` entry—namely something ISO formatted) will be formatted as "(visited on )".

using the bits of source you have provided, and putting these changes into place you get:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage {biblatex}
\usepackage {filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{t100b,
  author = {Interbrand},
  title = {Best Global Brands 2012},
  url = {http://www.interbrand.com/en/best-global-brands/2012/Best-Global-Brands-2012-Brand-View.aspx},
  year = {2012},
  urldate = {2012-12-19},
}
\end{filecontents}
% use graphics and floating figures
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

Some text with a citation \cite{t100b}

\printbibliography[title={Internet}, type=online]

\end{document}
```

[image]