# Reorder "Note" field at the end of the reference

Tags: biblatex

I would like to reorder fields in Biblatex printbibliography output. My purpose is to put the "note" field at the very end.

Right now, there is a possible confusion with the page. If the note refers to another edition, the reader can think the pages are for this other edition.

[image]

This is a different question than [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87790/years-before-note-with-biblatex) (the author was using "note" for "urldate"). It quite similar to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46804/can-i-reorder-the-fields-in-a-biblatex-bibliography) but the complicated solution is dated of 2012. There is maybe a simpler way to achieve this in recent biblatex versions

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{test,
   author =   {Author},
   title =    {Title},
   journaltitle = {Journal},
   year =     2015,
   number = 2,
   volume = 167,
   pages = {67--88},
   note = {Reprinted under the name "Title2"}}

 \end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `addendum` field, which normally comes very close to the end (but not exactly at the end).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `addendum` field is normally displayed almost at the very end of an entry (in most cases it would be at the end), so that would be an obvious candidate for you if you don't want to mess with the style itself.

You can map `note` to `addendum` with sourcemaps so you don't even have to change your `.bib` file

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  year =     2015,
  number = 2,
  volume = 167,
  pages = {67--88},
  note = {Reprinted under the name \mkbibquote{Title2}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \step[fieldsource=note]
      \step[fieldset=addendum, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldset=note, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really wanted to move the `note` for all entry types you would have to redefine or patch the bibliography drivers and the the macro `note+pages`. You can then re-insert the `note` field after `addendum` and `pubstate` (again, technically that is not really at the end, but it makes sense to put it there instead of putting it at the very end).

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand*{\removenotefromdriver}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{note}}
    {}
    {}{}}
\forcsvlist{\removenotefromdriver}
  {book,collection,proceedings,
   inbook,incollection,inproceedings,
   booklet,manual,misc,online,patent,
   periodical,report,thesis,unpublished}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}}
```

---

If this really is about a reprint of an article, I wholeheartedly recommend looking into the **`related` function** of `biblatex`. You could try something like

```
@article{test,
  author       = {Author},
  title        = {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  year         = 2015,
  number       = 2,
  volume       = 167,
  pages        = {67--88},
  related      = {test2},
  relatedtype  = {reprintas},
}
@inbook{test2,
  author    = {Author},
  title     = {Title2},
  booktitle = {Collected Works},
}
```

which would give

[image]

Comment: The related function is really the best solution. I was using `reprintof` relation but it creates a entry for the reprinted article. IMHO there shouldn't be an entry if it is exactly the same article. I didn't know `reprintas` relation and it does exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @ppr It does indeed create a new entry, but you don't have to cite it, it will only appear in the bibliography if you explicitly or implicitly cite it. You can avoid that by adding `options   = {skipbib=true}, ` to the related entry. That way it will never appear in the bibliography even with `\nocite{*}`