# biblatex: show "note" or "addendum" with style "reading"

Tags: biblatex

### TL;DR

I used Overleaf and I had to `clear cached files` in order to get the correct output.

[image]

---

- This shouldn't be difficult but I couldn't figure it out myself.
- I want to use the `reading` style of `biblatex`.
- **Goal:** I also want to **show the `note` field** (or `addendum` if that is easier) in the bibliography (**at the end of each entry**, ideally in a separate parapgraph).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style = authoryear,
    bibstyle = reading, % <-- Important
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  note = {note},
  addendum = {addendum}, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434931
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use the `annotation` field, which is already used by the style? (Or `abstract`, as appropriate).

Comment: Your MWE produces https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVpSC.png for me complete with `note` and `addendum` output. Those fields are for inline values. If you want a longer commentary the `annotation` field as suggested by gusbrs seems more appropriate.

Comment: @moewe Oh, thanks. Then I have to double-check my MWE (used a current Overleaf),

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @moewe I double-checked my MWE and I had to "clear cached files" before I saw the same output as you, thanks for the help.

Comment: @gusbrs Do you want to provide a short answer ((so that I can accept/reward)?

Comment: @moewe Sorry again for the bad MWE. In the past, Overleaf was more robust according to my fragile memory. Not sure why I did not catch the mistake before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex`'s `reading` style already offers support for a number of fields not typically used by the standard styles, and meant to track "additional information" regarding the entry, namely: `annotation`, `abstract`, `library`, and `file`. Given your description, `annotation` seems to be the best suited for your purposes, and it gets typeset on a separate paragraph, as you want.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style = authoryear,
    bibstyle = reading, % <-- Important
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  note = {note},
  addendum = {addendum}, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434931
  annotation = {A longer annotation, to be typeset in a separate paragraph.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{key,sigfridsson,itzhaki}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]