# biber: backref after related entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, back-referencing

In the following MWE (compiled with `pdflatex`, `biber`, and again `pdflatex`), the back reference is printed in front of the ‘reprinted as’ (see screenshot). Is there a way to put the back reference at the end?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Kelly,
  author        = {Kelly, G.\ M.},
  title         = {Basic concepts of enriched category theory},
  publisher     = {Cambridge University Press},
  address       = {Cambridge},
  series        = {London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series},
  number        = {64},
  year          = {1982},
  isbn          = {978-0-521-28702-9},
  related       = {KellyNew},
  relatedstring = {Reprinted as}
}

@article{KellyNew,
  author        = {Kelly, G.\ M.},
  title         = {Basic concepts of enriched category theory},
  pages         = {1–136},
  volume        = {10},
  journal       = {Repr.\ Theory Appl.\ Categ.},
  volume        = {10},
  year          = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Kelly}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Backref in front of related]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of these elements is defined by the bibliography driver. All standard drivers end like this

```
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

which means that the backref is shown before related entries.

The best solution™ would be to move the `pageref` invocation to the place where you want it to appear. Of course this is tedious and repetitive what with there being at least 19 drivers to modify. We can abbreviate this by using `xpatch` to patch the drivers and an internal macro to loop over all types.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand*{\movepageref}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
     \usebibmacro{pageref}}
    {}
    {}
    {}%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{finentry}}
    {\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
     \usebibmacro{pageref}
     \usebibmacro{finentry}}
    {}
    {}%
}
\makeatletter
\let\do\movepageref
\abx@doentrytypes
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Kelly,
  author        = {Kelly, G. M.},
  title         = {Basic concepts of enriched category theory},
  publisher     = {Cambridge University Press},
  address       = {Cambridge},
  series        = {London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series},
  number        = {64},
  year          = {1982},
  isbn          = {978-0-521-28702-9},
  related       = {KellyNew},
  relatedstring = {Reprinted as},
}
@article{KellyNew,
  author        = {Kelly, G. M.},
  title         = {Basic concepts of enriched category theory},
  pages         = {1–136},
  volume        = {10},
  journal       = {Repr. Theory Appl. Categ.},
  volume        = {10},
  year          = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Kelly}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: G. M. Kelly. Basic concepts of enriched category theory. London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series 64. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1982. isbn: 978-0-521-28702-9. Reprinted as “Basic concepts of enriched category theory”. In: Repr. Theory Appl. Categ. 10 (2005), pp. 1–136 (cit. on p. 1).]

---

A conceptually less satisfying but much shorter solution would be to copy the `pageref` bibmacro into a new macro, redefine `pageref` to do nothing and use the copy in `finentry`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref]{biblatex}

\letbibmacro*{orig:pageref}{pageref}

\renewbibmacro{pageref}{}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{orig:pageref}%
  \finentry}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Kelly,
  author        = {Kelly, G. M.},
  title         = {Basic concepts of enriched category theory},
  publisher     = {Cambridge University Press},
  address       = {Cambridge},
  series        = {London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series},
  number        = {64},
  year          = {1982},
  isbn          = {978-0-521-28702-9},
  related       = {KellyNew},
  relatedstring = {Reprinted as},
}
@article{KellyNew,
  author        = {Kelly, G. M.},
  title         = {Basic concepts of enriched category theory},
  pages         = {1–136},
  volume        = {10},
  journal       = {Repr. Theory Appl. Categ.},
  volume        = {10},
  year          = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Kelly}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

My attempt was inspired by [Can I reorder the fields in a biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46804/can-i-reorder-the-fields-in-a-biblatex-bibliography).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate+pageref+related}{%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \clearfield{addendum}%
  \clearfield{pubstate}%
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \clearfield{related}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \clearlist{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock}

\xpretobibmacro{doi+eprint+url}{\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate+pageref+related}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{eprint}{\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate+pageref+related}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{url+urldate}{\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate+pageref+related}}{}{}


\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Kelly,
  author        = {Kelly, G.\ M.},
  title         = {Basic concepts of enriched category theory},
  publisher     = {Cambridge University Press},
  address       = {Cambridge},
  series        = {London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series},
  number        = {64},
  year          = {1982},
  isbn          = {978-0-521-28702-9},
  related       = {KellyNew},
  relatedstring = {Reprinted as},
}

@article{KellyNew,
  author        = {Kelly, G.\ M.},
  title         = {Basic concepts of enriched category theory},
  pages         = {1–136},
  volume        = {10},
  journal       = {Repr.\ Theory Appl.\ Categ.},
  volume        = {10},
  year          = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
%\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Kelly}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]